# Formula to combine variable and cell references

Tags: excel, vba

I have been looking for hours for a solution but couldn't find any. I am an absolute beginner in VBA and couldn't figure this out for myself. The thing I would like to do is that VBA enters in a cell a formula that will contain a value extracted from a variable and then subtracts all the below cells. The cells below could change which would affect the overall value so I need to leave it as dynamic. (e.g: Cell A1 should look like this: =500-A2-A3-A4.. etc).
The code looks like this at the moment. So far it only enters the value from the variable

```
crnt = Cells(5, "D").Value
Range("E60").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, crnt - 1).Activate
rev = ActiveCell.Value
Range("E9").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(0, crnt - 1).Select
ActiveCell.Value = rev
```

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  But, in general, you can try to record a macro while accomplishing your task manually.  Then clean up the macro (e.g. remove all the Selects, Activates, and other useless commands) until you have what you want.  You can do an internet or SO search for information on how to accomplish those tasks.

Comment: Unfortunately recording won't work. I load finance data from another report which appear in let's say cell A1. I need the value only from this cell to appear in e.g cell B1. But I not only need to have the value in B1, but I need to have it incorporated in a formula as described above (i.e =500-b2-b3..etc). If I record the macro it will always enter into the cell one specific number, however the next month I would get a completely different one from finance. I hope this clear a bit up on what I would like to achieve.

Comment: If you have a value in some cell that you want to use as a constant, why does that preclude you from recording a macro?  Just use an absolute addressing mode.  If the value is coming from a data connection; again, why does that preclude you from recording a macro?

Comment: I don't want to just simply link the source value. After I am done with my updates I pass the files (~150 where I need to do this) to other users (with varying excel knowledge). I want the other users the clearly see the number in B1 and the formula as well.

Comment: You should be able to do that when you clean up and edit the recorded macro.

Comment: Sorry, I probably explaining it wrong, or I don't understand how I should do this, but when recording and cleaning up I get the following code: Range("M60").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=4.89402524201477-R[1]C-R[3]C-R[4]C-R[6]C"
The problem with this that as you can see no matter what the value will be that I am copying and pasting my formula will leave the old value of 4.89.

Comment: And where did the 4.89 come from?

Comment: It is copied from cell M60. But next month it will be in N60, the next int O60, etc. And although the recorded macro would copy it and paste the value of that, but it would always overwrite it with the formula "=4.89402524201477-R[1]C-R[3]C-R[4]C-R[6]C" since that's what it recoded the first time. So instead of this I want to have the number in a variable. It would take that variable each month from the correct cell, then would write the formula with the variable, with the correct number in it.

Comment: All you need to do is substitute the appropriate cell value.  Dim myVar As Double
'change depending on the month
   myVar = Range("M60")
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=" & myVar & "-R[1]C-R[3]C-R[4]C-R[6]C"

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did solve it. sorry for not being too clear in the beginning so thanks for the extra patience as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want this one:

```
InVal = 500          ' input value
Cells("A1").FormulaLocal = "=" & CStr(InVal) & "-A2-A3-A4"
```

or in a loop

```
Dim InVal() as Variant
InVal = Range("M60:Z60").Value

For i = LBound(InVal) to UBound(InVal)
    Cells(1, i + 1).FormulaLocal = "=" & CStr(Val(InVal(i))) & "-" & Cells(2, i + 1).Address & "-" & Cells(3, i + 1).Address & "-" & Cells(4, i + 1).Address 
Next i
```

All you need to do is to play with .Address and the strings to compile the formula.

Comment: Perfect! I knew this was something easy, but couldn't get my head around it. Thanks @AcsErno